# Tor for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: tor

Could someone tell me, step by step, exactly, how should I install correctly Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

also, how can I be sure that it is working properly?

Thanks

Comment: You download it from the [Tor site](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en), extract the file, and then run the program.

Comment: I did it. But I have problems checking the signature. It says (in the terminal): can't verify signature. cannot open file.....

Comment: Post the command you are running to get that error.

Comment: ~$ gpg  --fingerprint 0x63FEE659
pub   2048R/63FEE659 2003-10-16
      Key fingerprint = 8738 A680 B84B 3031 A630  F2DB 416F 0610 63FE E659
uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@torproject.org>
uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@debian.org>
uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@double-helix.org>
sub   2048R/EB399FD7 2003-10-16

xyz@xyz-ESPRIMO-Mobile-V6545:~$ gpg --verify tor-browser-2.2.33-2_en-US.exe.asc tor-browser-2.2.33-2_en-US.exe
gpg: can't open `tor-browser-2.2.33-2_en-US.exe.asc'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error

Comment: I replaced 2.2.33-2 with 3.5.4 but sstill error.

Comment: There are 2 files in my Home/Downloads: tor-browser-linux32-3.5.4_en-US.tar.xz.asc     and  tor-browser-linux32-3.5.4_en-US.tar.xz

Comment: You either need to verify the first one (tar.xz.asc), or unzip the .xz file (right click menu) to get the contents. And if you're running Tor on Ubuntu, you don't want to do the .exe file.

Comment: /home/xyz/Downloads/tor-browser-linux32-3.5.4_en-US.tar.xz.asc /home/xyz/Downloads/tor-browser-linux32-3.5.4_en-US.tar.xz
gpg: Signature made Wed 09 Apr 2014 12:09:01 AM EEST using RSA key ID 63FEE659
gpg: Good signature from "Erinn Clark <erinn@torproject.org>"
gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@debian.org>"
gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@double-helix.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key finger: 8738 A680 B84B 3031 A630  F2DB 416F 0610 63FE E659

Comment: Above is what I got latest. I did not unzip the tar.xz file, yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you're running Tor on Ubuntu, you don't want to do the .exe file" ? What is "do an .exe file ?

Comment: That output looks like what the Tor project says you should get, so it's good.

Comment: When you unpack the .xz, you will have different files to use. The .exe is for Windows.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. When I double - click the file "start-tor-browser" Tor browser starts. That file is a shell script. It asks me to choose: run in Terminal, Display or Run. I always choose "Run". is it a mistake? Also, why is that Ubuntu 12.04 LTS does not ask me for password, as it does when I launch other applications?

Answer (score 1):

When checking the signature of the download, the signature should be checked against the `.tar.xz.asc` file, corresponding to the `.tar.xz` archive. As explained on the [Tor page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en), This should include the following message:

```
gpg: Good signature
```

Once the signature is verified, the archive can be extracted. This can be done by right clicking and selecting the "Extract" option.

Navigating into this folder will then allow running Tor. The `.exe` file is for use under Windows. The `start-tor-browser` is a script that will run under Ubuntu to start Tor.

This will give three options: Terminal, Display, and Run.

- Terminal will run the script in a terminal, which is useful if you want to see output from the script
- Display will just open the script for editing with a text editor
- Run will just run the script like any other program

Run is fine unless you are troubleshooting or need to see something that is shown in the terminal.

It should not ask you for a password. Programs that do important tasks like installing software need to ask permission to do so, which is why Software Center and others might ask for a password. The Tor browser shouldn't need any extra permissions.